# Uploading a new process to an already existing Bonita Application that runs on Docker

Tags: business-process-management, bonita

So, I was reading the documentation, and I found out that only users with an Enterprise subscription can compile a [Docker image of the Bonita Runtime](https://documentation.bonitasoft.com/bonita/latest/runtime/bonita-docker-installation). But then, I read [in here](https://documentation.bonitasoft.com/bonita/latest/build-a-process-for-deployment) that it is also possible to deploy a process, and then install it to an already existing application through the Bonita Administrator Application.

So, technically, I could just create a Bonita Application, put it inside of a Docker by following [these instructions](https://documentation.bonitasoft.com/bonita/latest/build-run/build-application), host that Docker in a service like AWS, and then upload all of the other applications and processes that I create over time to that same instance, couldn't I?

Now, regarding the upload and installation of these new applications, there is no current way of doing it through the API, right? The POST method for the Create a living application endpoint is deprecated since v9.0.0. Thus, the only way to install a new application inside of the Docker would be to copy the compiled app that I want to add inside of the container, and then install it using the admin app. Am I getting this right?

Thanks in advance for your time!